# How do I capture mutable variables?

Tags: rust

```
struct Level{
    i_vec: ~[int]
}
pub struct GameManager{
    lvl: Level
}
impl GameManager {
    pub fn new() -> GameManager{
        GameManager {lvl: Level{i_vec: ~[]}}
    }
    pub fn new_game(f: ~fn()) {
        do spawn {
            f();
        }
    }
    pub fn default_game_loop(lvl: &Level ,f: &fn() ){
        loop {
            f();
            break;
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut gm = GameManager::new();
    do GameManager::new_game(){
        // I know I could move "gm" here, but I would like
        // to know how to capture mutable variables.
        do GameManager::default_game_loop(&gm.lvl){

        }
    }

}
/*
/home/maik/source/test.rs:28:43: 28:45 error: mutable variables cannot be implicitly captured
/home/maik/source/test.rs:28         do GameManager::default_game_loop(&gm.lvl){
                                                                        ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 101]
*/
```

How do I capture mutable variables?

I also tried to make those functions methods but then everything broke because it tried to move itself into the closure like

```
do gm.default_game_loop(){
    let level = &gm.lvl;    
}
```

Is there a self parameter that I can use? Because gm itself should be available in the closure like

```
do gm.default_game_loop(){
        let level = self.lvl;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that you cannot directly share memory between two tasks. The traditional way to handle this is to move data to the thread. Here's an example:

```
use std::task;

struct Level {
    i_vec: ~[int]
}
pub struct GameManager {
    lvl: Level
}
impl GameManager {
    pub fn new() -> GameManager {
        GameManager { lvl: Level { i_vec: ~[] } }
    }
    pub fn new_game<A: Send>(a: A, f: ~fn(A)) {
        task::spawn_with(a, f)
    }
    pub fn default_game_loop(lvl: &Level, f: &fn()) {
        loop {
            f();
            break;
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut gm = GameManager::new();
    do GameManager::new_game(gm) |gm| {
        // I know I could move "gm" here, but I would like
        // to know how to capture mutable variables.
        do GameManager::default_game_loop(&gm.lvl) {

        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit more tricky if you need to somehow share mutable state across multiple threads. To do that, you could either set up a task that owns the mutable state and modifications are done through [std::comm::stream](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/comm/index.html) channels, or through a mutex-protected [extra::arc::RWArc](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/extra/arc/struct.RWArc.html).